# Can't insert into database using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate to implement a register function and I encountered the following problems...

```
Hibernate: insert into Customer (address, isMember, mobile, name, password, rank, reward, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.POJO.Customer]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2285)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2678)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1028)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.dao.impl.CustomerDAOImpl.addCustomer(CustomerDAOImpl.java:34)
    at com.service.CustomerService.doRegister(CustomerService.java:12)
    at com.action.RegisterAction.execute(RegisterAction.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL121014203335200' defined on 'CUSTOMER'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2265)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL121014203335200' defined on 'CUSTOMER'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 84 more
```

Here is how I configure the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/orderonline;create=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">user</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate’s current session context -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  </session-factory>
```

I also created a HibernateUtil.java

```
    public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static final AnnotationConfiguration config;

    static {
        try {
            config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
            config.addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class);
            config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Here comes the Entity class

```
package com.POJO;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Customer")
public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String mobile;
    private String address;
    private int isMember;
    private int rank;
    private double reward;

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public int getIsMember() {
        return isMember;
    }

    public void setIsMember(int isMember) {
        this.isMember = isMember;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public double getReward() {
        return reward;
    }

    public void setReward(double reward) {
        this.reward = reward;
    }

}
```

Here is how I create the table

```
create table app.customer
(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) primary key, 
  title varchar(10),
  name varchar(20),
  password varchar(10),
  mobile varchar(10),
  address varchar(50),
  isMember int,
  rank int,
  reward double
)
```

and I have added the `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` next to `@Id`

but there comes another problem

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get or update next value
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TransactionHelper$1Work.doWork(TransactionHelper.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.Isolater$JdbcDelegate.delegateWork(Isolater.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.Isolater.doIsolatedWork(Isolater.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TransactionHelper.doWorkInNewTransaction(TransactionHelper.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.id.TableGenerator.generate(TableGenerator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator.generate(TableHiLoGenerator.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:547)
    at com.dao.impl.CustomerDAOImpl.addCustomer(CustomerDAOImpl.java:33)
    at com.service.CustomerService.doRegister(CustomerService.java:12)
    at com.action.RegisterAction.execute(RegisterAction.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'HIBERNATE_UNIQUE_KEY' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.TableGenerator.doWorkInCurrentTransaction(TableGenerator.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TransactionHelper$1Work.doWork(TransactionHelper.java:61)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'HIBERNATE_UNIQUE_KEY' does not exist.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    ... 88 more
```

How can I solve this problem...? I have tried many ways... Could any one give a hint on this ?

Comment: Seems like your data is not good - are you trying to insert the same record twice?

Comment: You have to post the Entity that you try to save too. I guess the issue is in the annotation of the primary key of the Customer.class. Do you have already records in the table "customer" ? What primary key do they have?

Comment: can u write the annotated class and the method you are trying to persist from.

Comment: @RonK even so the data will be populated twice with 2 different ids.

Comment: @ProgMania It depends on the Entity and its annotations and the way the Op populates the values of these entities.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568330/

Comment: @ProgMania: No, because `id` is in the column list in the query.

Comment: @RonK I have posted the entity class, I am using the derby database to generate the id column, could that be the problem ?

Comment: You need to define how the ids are populated, look into the @GeneratedValue annotation

Comment: Can you try to put the `@GeneratedValue` next to the `@Id` annotation in your customer class.

Comment: @kmb385 I am using the derby to generated the `id`,

Comment: @Z.pyyyy you still need to inform hibernate of that.  Is it using a sequence or an autonumber?

Comment: @kmb385 which I used in database is a sequence, starts from 1 and increases by 1

Answer (score 3):

The Customer pojo does not define how the ID for the class is set.  You need to look at adding an @GeneratedValue annotation and define an appropriate strategy.

Checkout: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec and look for the Generating the Indentifier section.  At the moment I'm assuming your entering duplicate keys.

Try something like:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId() { 
    return id; 
}
```

There are four basic options for the strategy, depending on how your ids are populated by derby:

AUTO - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB

TABLE - table holding the id

IDENTITY - identity column

SEQUENCE - sequence

If you are using a sequence you can also try, where ENTITY_SEQ is the name of the sequence object in derby:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_seq_gen") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq_gen", sequenceName="ENTITY_SEQ") 
public int getId() { 
    return id; 
}
```

Reference: [@GeneratedValue with strategy=GenerationType.AUTO generates repeated value after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653497/generatedvalue-with-strategy-generationtype-auto-generates-repeated-value-after)

Comment: So I should define a sequence in derby and I should also defined a `@GeneratedValue` in the entity class ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll venture a guess that you're not explicitly setting the `id` on the POJO, perhaps faultily depending on a DB autonumbering scheme? Have a look at the Hibernate `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a self written statement to insert the entity?

You might consider to use the org.hibernate.Session::persist and org.hibernate.Session::saveOrUpdate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the generating method.
The easiest way to set the generating value for the id is to let the db engine itself to set the generating value for the id column, just like this.

```
    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return Id;
        }
```

Comment: I tried that but it comes up with another problem...

Comment: @Z.pyyyy what's the other problem you have ? show it to me and i'll help you solving it out, i'm using this with mysql and setting the id column in mysql to be auto increment attr, and it works very fine.

Comment: I tried as you said, but it shows sth like `Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column 'ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.` ...

Comment: check your db that it assigned auto increment to the id column, and you may check my edit adding @Column annotation.

Comment: `ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) primary key` this is how I create an ID number for the Customer table, but it still doesnt work...

Comment: then try to use AUTO method in the generating type.
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) and check http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html